# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume-driver" : configmap "spark-drv-8f76948a32f75d9c-conf-map" not found

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

My spark jobs and job drivers created from a scheduledsparkapplication are giving me this error in my kubernetes cluster, and it floods the alerting even though the jobs are running fine, and there are no errors in any of the logs.

I can't just filter these errors in the event of the alert being an actual true positive ( instead of the false positive I have received so far ).

The thing is, the error is not consistent with the behaviour of the jobs. Sometimes it says even though the configmap is there, sometimes there is no error, even when the configmap is not there. Sometimes the error fires then after half a minute it vanishes ( mind you the alert has been already sent ). Sometimes the configmap is created a few seconds after the creation of the driver pods. I even tried to add a busyboy init-container to maybe delay the mounting, but the mounting is instantenous with the creation of the pod.

I have searched the github of the spar operator, and stackoverflow, but haven't found anything yet.
If any of you have any leads on this, please share.

If you'd need more logs or configs please say so.

Obviously one part is to make sure that the configmap is created before the driver pod, is there any way with these to make a specific number of seconds elapse?

I even tried to add a busyboy init-container to maybe delay the mounting, but the mounting is instantenous with the creation of the pod.